# MPAndroidChart Scatter Chart data point markers and connecting the dots

Tags: android, scatter-plot, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

In an application for scatter data I want to have the data points connected by a line and disable the automatic labels that show up when I plot just a few points.

I've listed my code below for reference,

Is this possible?  Thanks

```
public class StaticPlottingFragment extends Fragment {


private static String TAG = "file_plotting_fragment";
private Typeface tf;
private int count = 100;
private LinkedList<DataPoint> mDataPoints;


public static StaticPlottingFragment newInstance() {
    return new StaticPlottingFragment();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.plotting_fragment, container, false);
    Log.i(TAG, " In OnCreateView inflate");
    // ScatterChart is initialized in plotting_fragment.xml
    ScatterChart mChart = (ScatterChart) view.findViewById(R.id.scatterChart1);
    // obtain legend object
    Legend legend = mChart.getLegend();
    // turn off legend
    legend.setEnabled(false);

    mChart.setData(readScatterDataFromFile(1, 10));
    mChart.invalidate();


    return view;
}


    protected ScatterData readScatterDataFromFile(int dataSets,int count) {

        ArrayList<String> xvals = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<IScatterDataSet> yset = new ArrayList<IScatterDataSet>();
        ScatterChart.ScatterShape[] shapes = ScatterChart.getAllPossibleShapes();

        DataLab dataLab = DataLab.get(getActivity());
        mDataPoints = dataLab.getDataPoints();

        for (int i = 0; i < dataSets; i++) {

            List<Entry> yentries = new ArrayList<Entry>();

            for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
                DataPoint dataPoint = mDataPoints.get(j);
                xvals.add("" + String.valueOf(dataPoint.gettVal()));
                yentries.add(new Entry(dataPoint.getxVal(), j));

            }
                    ScatterDataSet ds = new ScatterDataSet(yentries, "label");
                    ds.setScatterShapeSize(12f);
                    ds.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue25));
                    ds.setScatterShapeSize(9f);
                    yset.add(ds);


            }
        ScatterData d2 = new ScatterData(xvals, yset);
        // d.setValueTypeface(tf);
        return d2;

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use a `CombinedChart` to do that.

Use `ScatterData` to draw your shapes, and `LineData` to connect them with lines.

You can find more on that in the example project on Github.

You can disable drawing the value labels on any data object by calling `data.setDrawValues(false)`.