# MPAndroid Chart connect different points on the scatterchart

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

[[image: How I want it to look][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fi0EF.jpg)

I have made a scatter plot with 3 different datasets. I want the lines between the points (in the same x-axis) to join such as to form the graph above. 
[image: How it looks]
This is how it looks right now, all I wanna do is to join them by a line. Is it possible with MPAndroid chart? I am currently using that library.

I tried to use combinedchart, but the result is this:

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612824/mpandroidchart-scatter-chart-data-point-markers-and-connecting-the-dots

Comment: What is meant by "use linedata to connect them with lines" ? I only have 3 datasets. How would I use linedata there? I put all my datapoints into scatterdata.

Comment: As I understand from his answer, he is saying to use `CombinedChart` instead of `ScatterData`. In that, use `ScatterData` to draw your shapes, and `LineChart` to connect them with lines.

Comment: I did use scatterdata to draw shapes. But my question is, how do I use the linechart to connect?

Comment: You will get outline of code by viewing this code: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/CombinedChartActivity.java

Comment: I know the syntax. My question is, say if I need to connect the three dots which are part of 3 different data sets, how would I do that? Like, logic wise.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't implemented `CombinedChart` yet. But as I see in that code, there are two functions, `generateLineData()` and `generateBarData()` used to generate two charts on same screen. In your case one should be `ScatterChart` and another should be `LineChart`.

Comment: Check Line #72, 73, 82 and 109.

Comment: If possible, can you please post your code of `CombinedChart`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112908/discussion-between-richeek-dey-and-dhruv).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it! I used a candlechart. That worked like a charm. Except I just had to put my high and low values.

```
CandleDataSet dataSet1 = new CandleDataSet(entries,"hr");

        CandleData candleData = new CandleData(time_steps,dataSet1);
        candleStickChart.setData(candleData);
        candleStickChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
        candleStickChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
        candleStickChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
        candleStickChart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
        candleStickChart.setDrawBorders(false);
        candleStickChart.getXAxis().setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFF37D63"));
        candleStickChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);


        candleStickChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
        candleStickChart.setDescription("");
        candleStickChart.getAxisLeft().setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFF37D63"));
        candleStickChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
        candleStickChart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        candleStickChart.setPinchZoom(false);
        candleStickChart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);
```